# Compute $E(e^{XY}\mid\sigma(X))$, where $Y$ is exponentially distributed and independent of $X$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Suppose that $X,Y$ are independent random variables on $(\Omega, F, P)$. Assume there is a number $a <1$ such that $P(X \le a) = 1$. Also assume that $Y$ is exponentially distributed with mean one. Calculate the expected value of $[e^{XY} \ | \ \sigma(X)]$.

I'm really not sure where to even begin, here. We've been going over conditional expectations in class, but haven't really talked about any ways to actually calculate them. I see that X is a bounded random variable, and that since Y is exponentially distributed, $P(Y \in B) = \chi_B e^{-x}$ for any $B$ in the sigma-field of Y. I just don't know how to put any of these facts together to actually find the expectation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $Pr(X<\lambda)=1$ then
\begin{align}
E(e^{XY}|\sigma(X))&=\int_0^{\infty}e^{Xy}\lambda e^{-\lambda y} dy\\
&=\int_0^{\infty}e^{(X-\lambda)y}\lambda dy\\
&=\frac{\lambda}{\lambda-X}
\end{align}

If $Pr(X<\lambda)<1$ then the conditional expectation does not exist, since $\sigma(X)$ includes realizations for $X$ for which the integral does not converge.

Comment: I know that this is probably a very silly question, but how did you know to do this to calculate the expectation? I guess I don't understand why we can set up that first equation that way - why does the expected value equal the integral of the random variables multiplied by the distribution of one of them? Is there a specific formula or idea that you're using here? (I'm sorry again for the dumb question)

Comment: @gesa This is not a bad question at all. Intuitively, when you condition on $X$ it is as if you know the value of $X$, hence it is not random anymore. Therefore the only "source of randomness" in $e^{XY}|\sigma(X)$ is through $Y$. Here we have independence therefore when we condition on $X$ the distribution of $Y$ remains unchanged.

Comment: Thank you so much! I see now where that came from.

Comment: Four small $x$ should read capital $X$.

Comment: @Did Many thanks for the comment. I just corrected it.

Comment: *Four* times, not just once. (Unrelated: I would be curious to see the OP who asked the question, provide a justification of the first equal sign in your answer...)